# Cambiar de color botones de la AppBar en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

¿Cómo cambiar el color de los botones de la AppBar?, en mi caso del botón de regreso, el color por  defecto es blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la mía me sale negro y quiero cambiarlo a blanco lo intente con los colores de acento y aun así no me cambia.

Comment: @NO54D es un ToolBar el que usas?

Comment: si es un toolbar @Elenasys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hacerlo programáticamente:

```
final Drawable upArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
upArrow.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

A partir de la API 23 pasó de  `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` a `abc_ic_ab_back_material`

Answer (score 2):

Con la siguiente función se puede aplicar a cualquier icono de la `AppBar`

```
public static void tintMenuItemIcon(Context context, Menu menu, int idItem, int color) {
    Drawable drawable = menu.findItem(idItem).getIcon();

    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable,color ); 
    menu.findItem(idItem).setIcon(drawable);
}
```

**Su uso:**

Es recomendable cambiar el color de los elementos del menú dentro de la `AppBar`en `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_routes, menu);

    GeneralUtils.tintMenuItemIcon(getActivity(), menu, R.id.action_sort, Color.WHITE);
    GeneralUtils.tintMenuItemIcon(getActivity(), menu, R.id.action_filter, Color.WHITE);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución sin código java es el de modificar el xml de stylo.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Si lo tienes en Light el botón de atrás lo colorea negro, pero con DarkActionBar lo colorea blanco